# Facebook Customer Chat Plugin Auto Scroll to bottom

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recenlty i have included Facebook Customer Chat Plugin 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin 
in my website and it is working fine except, once a user login to facebook chat plugin and reload the same page or go to any other pages of website where this chat plugin is enabled, the page automatically scroll to bottom, this problem only occurs in Google Chrome ;_;

you can check this out here url https://www.coderare.com/

Comment: An unregistered user posted in an 'answer' which may be deleted from review: "No, it does not only occur on Chrome. I have the same problem on the iPhone 6 / Safari.".

Answer (score 8):

After much trial and error I found it was the anchor tag within Facebook's "iframe src:...", and also the problem is limited to Chrome, anyway here's the fix:

```
.fb_dialog, .fb_reset {position: fixed !important;z-index: 10000 !important;}
```

You may not need the z-index, but included it as I needed it

Hope this helps as it has driven me insane! Not the most elegant solution but it works and avoids a lot of JS

Comment: I was about to lose my hopes on this one, but seriously i don't have words for you! absolutely did a outstanding job here worked like charm! God Bless you!

Comment: This deserves more recognition! humble question why does the position: fixed needed in order for the z-index to work? Since without it the chat bubble still appears over other elements. But if you add that line it suddenly "forced" to stay below.